# Oracle EDT/EST time to GMT conversion

Tags: oracle, timestamp

all dates which we store in oracle are in EDT(summer) and EST(winter). I need a way to convert that date to UTC/GMT.

The conversion should be based on the db date and not the servers local TZ.
In other words if the date in the resultset is between:

```
"11/02/2014 02:00:00" ---> "03/08/2015 01:59:59": TZ offset = "-0500"
"03/08/2015 02:00:00" ---> "11/01/2015 01:59:59": TZ offset = "-0400".
```

And same for previous years. 
Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Are you looking maybe for: `some_date_column at time zone 'GMT'`?

Comment: what is SOME_DATE_COLUMN?

Comment: I tried Select **AT TIME ZONE dbtimezone**, but I am always getting  -05:00. I guess would I run it in December it would return  -04:00.
Is there now way to return the right offset related to the date in the resultset ?

Comment: `DBTIMEZOME` is a fix value and usually never change (even not in summer/winter). What is the datatype of your column?

Comment: `some_date_column` is some column defined as date in your table. As you chose to hide your table definition from us, I had to come up with some name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `some_date_column` is actually a date column then you can turn it into a timestamp with time zone using a cast (from date to timestamp) and [the `from_tz` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10592/functions068.htm) with a region that has the EST/EDT change defined:

```
with t (some_date_column) as (
  select to_date('11/02/2014 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all
  select to_date('03/08/2014 01:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all
  select to_date('03/08/2015 03:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all
  select to_date('11/01/2015 00:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all
  select to_date('11/01/2015 01:59:59', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
  union all
  select to_date('11/02/2015 02:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual
)
select t.some_date_column,
  cast(t.some_date_column as timestamp) as some_timestamp,
  from_tz(cast(t.some_date_column as timestamp), 'America/New_York')
    as some_timestamp_tz
from t;

SOME_DATE_COLUMN    SOME_TIMESTAMP      SOME_TIMESTAMP_TZ         
------------------- ------------------- ---------------------------
11/02/2014 02:00:00 11/02/2014 02:00:00 11/02/2014 02:00:00 -05:00 
03/08/2014 01:59:59 03/08/2014 01:59:59 03/08/2014 01:59:59 -05:00 
03/08/2015 03:00:00 03/08/2015 03:00:00 03/08/2015 03:00:00 -04:00 
11/01/2015 00:59:59 11/01/2015 00:59:59 11/01/2015 00:59:59 -04:00 
11/01/2015 01:59:59 11/01/2015 01:59:59 11/01/2015 01:59:59 -05:00 
11/02/2015 02:00:00 11/02/2015 02:00:00 11/02/2015 02:00:00 -05:00
```

This doesn't quite line up with the ranges in your question. There is no 02:00 when you move from EST to EDT, so I've used 03:00 in the demo CTE instead; and as the period between 01:00 and 02:00 is (sort of) repeated when you go the other way from EDT to EST the offset for a plain time in that hour is ambiguous, and Oracle is choosing to treat it as -05:00 rather than -04:00.

If you want the UTC equivalent of the EST/EDT time then you can then use [`at time zone`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions007.htm), and optionally cast back to a date:

```
...
select t.some_date_column,
  from_tz(cast(t.some_date_column as timestamp), 'America/New_York')
    at time zone 'UTC' as utc_timestamp_tz,
  cast(from_tz(cast(t.some_date_column as timestamp), 'America/New_York')
    at time zone 'UTC' as date) as utc_date
from t;

SOME_DATE_COLUMN    UTC_TIMESTAMP_TZ            UTC_DATE          
------------------- --------------------------- -------------------
11/02/2014 02:00:00 11/02/2014 07:00:00 +00:00  11/02/2014 07:00:00
03/08/2014 01:59:59 03/08/2014 06:59:59 +00:00  03/08/2014 06:59:59
03/08/2015 03:00:00 03/08/2015 07:00:00 +00:00  03/08/2015 07:00:00
11/01/2015 00:59:59 11/01/2015 04:59:59 +00:00  11/01/2015 04:59:59
11/01/2015 01:59:59 11/01/2015 06:59:59 +00:00  11/01/2015 06:59:59
11/02/2015 02:00:00 11/02/2015 07:00:00 +00:00  11/02/2015 07:00:00
```

If your original column is a timestamp (with no time zone information) rather than a date then you can skip the first cast from date to timestamp, but still use `from_tz` to specify it's original region.